# Vibration of pulley and string system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

So here's the statement:

A pulley of a mass $M$ is hanged using a spring (stiffness of the string being $k_1$), as shown in the image. What is the frequency of the pulley's oscillation?

[image]

So that's as far as I could get:

Linear motion equation:
$$T_2+T_1-mg=ma \tag{1}$$
Where $T_2$ is string tension on the spring side ($T_2=-kx$) and $T_1$ being string tension on the other side.

Now for the rotational equation:
$$R(T_2-T_1)=I\alpha \tag{2}$$

$$a=R\alpha\tag{3}$$

$$I=\frac{mR^2}{2}\tag{4}$$
Now I have a feeling that the problem should be solved using the equations:

$$x'' + w^2x=0$$

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{w}$$

In this case $x''=a$. From the equations (2), (3) and (4) we derive that

$$T_2-T_1=\frac{ma}{2}\tag{5}$$

And adding (5) and (1) we get

$$-2T_2+mg+\frac{3}{2}ma=0$$

or

$$2kx+mg+\frac{3}{2}ma=0$$

And there I'm stuck. Could anyone tell if at least I'm going to the right direction? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the pulley 'slide' along the string? Or is the string on both sides flexible? If it can only slide you need some kind of damping term but it is hard to see from the small picture.

Comment: The pulley slides along the string, and the string itself is not flexible, only the spring

Answer (score 0):

To get to natural frequency with 1DOF you need to work out the equations in the form

$$ \ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x $$

where $x$ is the displacement from the static equilibrium and $\omega$ the frequency in $\rm rad/s$. To get to frequency in $\rm Hz$ you take $f=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$.

Comment: Well I wrote that in the question, the problem is I can't find a way to work out the equations this way... Maybe there's a mistake in my equations?

Comment: I suggest you play close attention that $x$ measured deformation **from equilibrium**. Since you have gravity you have to define $x$ such that when $x=0$ all tensions counter act gravity.

Comment: Also check that when the pulley turns positively (CCW) they height is increased or decreased, in order to get the sign of $a=R \alpha$ or $a=-R \alpha$ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: diagram]

Please refer the diagram shown for reference points.

Dude, before jumping into all these equations try to have a feel of what's gonna happen.

Since the string on the right hand side is inextensible, the maximum possible motion in the vertical direction is pi*R where R is the radius of the pulley. Also, if  we assume frictional force exists between the spring/pulley or rope/pulley, the pulley will also rotate & otherwise it will not. In case of perfectly smooth surface, the pulley will execute Simple Harmonic motion i.e. point B will move to point C [assuming sufficient M], C will move upwards by pi*R. Then it will again revert to its initial state.

However, if friction, a non-conservative force, exists, along with downward motion, the pulley will also rotate about its centre. In addition, it will also execute simple harmonic motion, but a damping term will also figure in your governing equation i.e. after a certain time [which will be given by the time-constant of the equation], the oscillations become barely noticeable.

Going back to equations,
the first one you wrote,
T2+T1-mg=ma
is ok.
T2=-kx
a=d2x/dt2
So it gives a second-order ODE in x w.r.t. t.
But the second one,
for frictionless pulley, alpha=0
So it cannot be written.
Similarly the third one,
is the tangential/rotational acceleration & not the vertical a which you have used in the first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Haven't read through, but you may try to use math LaTex for those equations.